# Creating additional Superuser in Django 1.6

Tags: django, admin, root

Is it possible to create more than one superusers in Django? When I create a new django app it automatically asks for creating a superuser. But I don't know how I can create more than one superuser to give admin access to other people ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

More: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser